# LibGdx Screen: render and lifecycle

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a problem, I think its related to Screen render and its lifecycle.
Basically I have two screens (Menu and Game). In GameScreen render method i call World.update and after that my Render. In hide method (of GameScreen) i dispose of the SpriteBatch from Redner class.

So when I change the screen from Game to Menu (within World.update) Java crashes. As far as I can tell, the dispose is making the crash.
So my question is, when i set a new screen in the middle of the render cycle, is that render cycle still going to finish with its old screen? Meaning, am I calling batch.dispose before the rendering was finished, and that is why i get the problem?

Thank you for all the help

```
public class GameScreen extends AbstractGameScreen {
    private static final String TAG = GameScreen.class.getName();

    private WorldController worldController;
    private WorldRenderer worldRenderer;

    private boolean paused;

    public GameScreen(Game game) {
        super(game);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float deltaTime) {
        // Do not update game world when paused
        if (!paused) {
            // Update game world by the time that has passed since last render time
            worldController.update(deltaTime);
        }
        // Sets the clear screen color to: Cornflower Blue
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0x64 / 255.0f, 0x95 / 255.0f, 0xed / 255.0f, 0xff / 255.0f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        // Render game world to screen
        worldRenderer.render();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        worldRenderer.resize(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() { // Similar as create method
        worldController = new WorldController(game);
        worldRenderer = new WorldRenderer(worldController);
        Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() { // Similar to dispose method
        worldRenderer.dispose();
        Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        paused = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        super.resume();
        // Only called on Android
        paused = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's basically correct. The screen that calls `setScreen` from within its `render` method will have `hide` called on itself and then will continue through the rest of its code in its `render` method. So you are killing your sprite batch right before trying to draw with it.

So don't call `dispose` from within your `hide` method. In fact, it is probably bad practice for a Screen to ever call `dispose` on itself. You can reserve that for the Game class that owns it. For example, you could do something like this in your game class:

```
@Override
public void render() {
    super.render();
    if (getScreen() != gameScreen && gameScreen != null) {
        gameScreen.dispose();
        gameScreen = null;
    }
}
```

By the way, you should probably put the SpriteBatch in your Game subclass and let all the different screens share it. It's a fairly big object to be allocating and deallocating for no reason.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. One more question. Looking at my two screens (main menu and game). What is best practice when switching between them, to live them or to dispose them. If I do not dispose them, should I then dispose the SpriteBatch of gameScreen while in menuScreen or not?

Comment: The SpriteBatch should only be disposed when the game is completely closing (in your Game class's `dispose` method) because you need it on every screen. It's a waste of time to deallocate it and allocate a new one. For the screens as a whole, there's no best practice because it depends on the game. I'm doing a very simple game where I can easily keep the entire game in memory at all times, so I never dispose screens. But if your memory use is getting high, you might need to. Menu screens likely don't use much, so maybe always keep the screens on except when switching from one stage to another.